# How to add table on click over each column in Highcharts Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am using [highcharts-react-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) as for using the highcharts. I can display the column graph which I want. The requirement is after clicking over each column, a table related to that column's detailed information needs to be displayed with some hyperlinks.
I am unable to create that Table.
Would like to prefer [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/), but any table is appreciated, and would like to close the table with a close button.
Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!!!

EDIT
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-kn1zu?file=/demo.jsx Added the code here.
Alert seems to be working but not a table.
I would like to see the table
[image]
there. The table should contain the details of the drill-down series along with that some more information I would like to add by passing an array. And should vanish when clicking on the Back button. Can u please help me how to do so? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywbgx1?file=index.js) is an example of how it can be done.
You are trying to return HTML from a function inside Highcharts. React is unaware of this thus, it does not render anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir for your response, it helped a lot. Just wanted to ask how to close the table when the graph is drilled up? Can u please help me with the same? Thank you!

Comment: Added drillupall event and that helped. Thank you!